# Do we have to re-publish the Web-site if we modify a part of the code in the aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If we make a slight modification of the code in the C# page or in the aspx page, do we have to republish the entire web-site after the modification?

I am using VS-2008 professional and the code is written in C#.

Comment: It depends on your modification.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, if you are connnected to the website using a ftp connection (Solution showing as ftp://ftp.somewebsite.com) then your alterations will be updated real time. If you are using a local copy of the website (offline website), you need to publish the entire website once your are done.

So to answer your question we need more information about how you setup your website in the solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two case of modification:

1. UI (HTML Code), you can just click to refresh the browser without having to rebuild the solution
2. Server Code (C# code), you have to click F6 in VS2008 and rebuild the solution

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which code you modify:

- if you make a change to the asp markup of the aspx , than you don't have to.
- if you change your code behind, then you will need to rebuild your
  project therefore you have to republish it.